# Out of range float values are not JSON complian when using save()

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, bokeh

I am iterating to save multiple maps, but when I enter the second iteration at save time it gives me an error. I already tried doing each iteration manually and there is no error regarding NaN values ​​or similar

This is my code:

```
for i in range(1,33):
    gdf = gdf[gdf['ID_1'] == i]
    gdf['MUNICIPIO'] = gdf['NAME_2'].apply(lambda x: x.lower())

    df_final = gdf.merge(archivo_csv, how = 'left', right_on = 'municipio', left_on = 'MUNICIPIO', suffixes = ("", "_2"))

    df_final.rename(columns={'ID_1':'id_estado', 'NAME_1':'estado', 'ID_2':'id_municipio'}, inplace = True)

    df_final = df_final[['id_municipio', 'MUNICIPIO', 'frecuencia', 'geometry']]

    df_final = df_final.fillna(0.1)

    archivo_json = json.loads(df_final.to_json())
    json_data = json.dumps(archivo_json)

    max_color = df_final['frecuencia'].max()
    gsource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)
    colores = brewer['YlGnBu'][9]
    colores = colores[::-1]
    color_mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette = colores, low = 0, high = max_color)
    hover = HoverTool(names = ['Municipios'], tooltips = [('Municipio', '@MUNICIPIO'), ('Frecuencia', '@frecuencia')])
    fig = figure()

    fig = figure(title = 'Frecuencia por municipio %i' % j,
             plot_height = 600,
             plot_width = 950,
             toolbar_location = None,
             tools = [hover])

    fig.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    fig.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
    fig.title.text_font_size = '20pt'

    fig.axis.visible = False

    fig.patches('xs', 'ys',
            source = gsource,
            fill_color = {'field': 'frecuencia', 'transform': color_mapper},
            line_color = 'black',
            line_width = 0.25,
            fill_alpha = 1,
            name = 'Municipios')

    output_file('Mapas/Mapa_fosas_%i.html' % i)
    save(fig)
```

And this is the full message error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14984\2022498390.py in <module>
    104     # Archivo HTML
    105     output_file('Mapas/Mapa_fosas_%i.html' % i)
--> 106     save(fig)
    107 
    108     # save(fig, 'Mapas/Mapa_fosas_%i.html' % i)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io\saving.py in save(obj, filename, resources, title, template, state)
     96 
     97     filename, resources, title = _get_save_args(state, filename, resources, title)
---> 98     _save_helper(obj, filename, resources, title, template, theme)
     99     return abspath(filename)
    100 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\io\saving.py in _save_helper(obj, filename, resources, title, template, theme)
    162     '''
    163     from ..embed import file_html
--> 164     html = file_html(obj, resources, title=title, template=template or FILE, theme=theme)
    165 
    166     with open(filename, mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as f:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\embed\standalone.py in file_html(models, resources, title, template, template_variables, theme, suppress_callback_warning, _always_new)
    344 
    345     with OutputDocumentFor(models_seq, apply_theme=theme, always_new=_always_new) as doc:
--> 346         (docs_json, render_items) = standalone_docs_json_and_render_items(models_seq, suppress_callback_warning=suppress_callback_warning)
    347         title = _title_from_models(models_seq, title)
    348         bundle = bundle_for_objs_and_resources([doc], resources)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\embed\util.py in standalone_docs_json_and_render_items(models, suppress_callback_warning)
    335     docs_json: Dict[ID, DocJson] = {}
    336     for doc, (docid, _) in docs.items():
--> 337         docs_json[docid] = doc.to_json()
    338 
    339     render_items: List[RenderItem] = []

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py in to_json(self)
    756         # this is a total hack to go via a string, needed because
    757         # our BokehJSONEncoder goes straight to a string.
--> 758         doc_json = self.to_json_string()
    759         return loads(doc_json)
    760 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\document\document.py in to_json_string(self, indent)
    788         )
    789 
--> 790         return serialize_json(json, indent=indent)
    791 
    792     def unhold(self) -> None:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bokeh\core\json_encoder.py in serialize_json(obj, pretty, indent, **kwargs)
    169         indent = 2
    170 
--> 171     return json.dumps(obj, cls=BokehJSONEncoder, allow_nan=False, indent=indent, separators=separators, sort_keys=True, **kwargs)
    172 
    173 

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in dumps(obj, skipkeys, ensure_ascii, check_circular, allow_nan, cls, indent, separators, default, sort_keys, **kw)
    232     if cls is None:
    233         cls = JSONEncoder
--> 234     return cls(
    235         skipkeys=skipkeys, ensure_ascii=ensure_ascii,
    236         check_circular=check_circular, allow_nan=allow_nan, indent=indent,

~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in encode(self, o)
    197         # exceptions aren't as detailed.  The list call should be roughly
    198         # equivalent to the PySequence_Fast that ''.join() would do.
--> 199         chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
    200         if not isinstance(chunks, (list, tuple)):
    201             chunks = list(chunks)

~\anaconda3\lib\json\encoder.py in iterencode(self, o, _one_shot)
    255                 self.key_separator, self.item_separator, self.sort_keys,
    256                 self.skipkeys, _one_shot)
--> 257         return _iterencode(o, 0)
    258 
    259 def _make_iterencode(markers, _default, _encoder, _indent, _floatstr,

ValueError: Out of range float values are not JSON compliant
```

[image]

I already looked in other pages and I can't find a similar error other than to treat the NaN values

Comment: please post the **full** error message including the stack trace as formatted text in the question itself.

Comment: as an aside, please always use the generic [python] tag for all python related questions

Comment: As the error states, JSON cannot represent NaN values. There is nothing Bokeh can do about that. However, if you put numeric data with NaN values in a suitably typed numpy array, then Bokeh will serialized the data in a different way that can accommodate NaN values. So perhaps you can try converting and plain lists inside `json_data` to numpy arrays first. Otherwise, as noted, you will simply have to remove the NaN values in some use-case appropriate way.